# Test if an ordered sequence of elements draw uniformly from two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have two groups of elements, `M` of type `A` and `N` of type `B`. All elements of `A` are equal. All elements in `B` are in equal. I want to now if a given sequence (like `AABABAABBAA`) of length M+N is compatible with drawing randomly from either `A` or `B` (taking into account that there are not the same ammount)

Comment: Are you, in effect, asking if AABABAABBAA etc. is likely a biased random binary? If so, *p* of  AA should be $1-p$ of BB and statistically indistinguishable from $p$ of AXA, and of AXXA and AXXXA etc. where X is A or B.

Comment: I am looking for an statistical test where the null hypothesis is that the A's are predominantly at the beginning.

Comment: However, that is not what the question says, nor is the motive for using such a test as opposed to using many other tests apparent.  Please clarify.

Comment: I might be wrong but if A's are predominantly at the beginning then the sequence was not build by drawing randomly from A or B

Comment: Not if there are more A's than B's overall. Might be random but biased toward the plurality of A's. Gave one answer already.